# how to invoke instance method with dyamic param name?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
class Sample {
  final String n1;
  final String n2;
  Sample({this.n1, this.n2});
  Sample copyWith({String n1}) {
    return Sample(n1: n1 ?? this.n1, n2: this.n2);
  }
}

void main() {
 dynamic d = Sample(n1: "one", n2: "two");
  print("Sample : ${d.n1}");
  var n1Name = "n1";
  dynamic d2 = d.copyWith("$n1Name" : "oneu"); // TODO i want to invoke copyWith dynamic param name
  print("Sample : ${d2.n1}");
}
```

i want to invoke copyWith with string constructed at runtime, is it possible ? if not how can i set field of class dynamically ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a Map which is dynamic key-value pairing that would be override by `.copyWith` method

```dart
class Sample {
  final String n1;
  final String n2;
  Sample({this.n1, this.n2});
  Sample copyWith([Map<String, dynamic> map =const {}]) {
    return Sample(n1: map["n1"] ?? this.n1, n2: this.n2);
  }
}

void main() {
 dynamic d = Sample(n1: "one", n2: "two");
  print("Sample : ${d.n1}");
  dynamic d2 = d.copyWith({"n1" : "oneu"}); // TODO i want to invoke copyWith dynamic param name
  print("Sample : ${d2.n1}");
}
```

Output:

```
Sample : one
Sample : oneu
```